# JMeter Webdriver Sampler

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance

Myself used web-driver sampler to run the JMeter script. The script is running fine, but I need to pause my page for 5 seconds after getting log in. This has to be done before my browser gets closed,

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

I already tried below mentioned script to pause the browser for few seconds but it doesn't works,

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10000)
```

Please suggest me a solution to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is as simple as:

```
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000)
```

See the following reference materials:

- [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)